# Uploading video to youtube through the API, and show progress bar

Tags: ajax, youtube, progress-bar, youtube-api

HI,
does anybody know if there's any option to show a real progress bar in my web site,  when uploading a video to youtube using their API? I believe that in order to do so , I would need to have the option to make ajax calls during the upload to get the state of the upload. am I right? and if I am, do you know if that's possible and how? I"m building a website using Asp.Net with C# .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about the YouTube API, but you don't necessarily need it, if you can count the bytes that you're sending.

The exact implementation of that depends largely on what environment you are using (which is missing from the question). Is this a desktop application or a web site, and if so, which language is it written in?

Comment: I'm using asp.net with C#. this is a website I'm building. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about ajax calls to Youtube i don't remember Youtube providing state of upload.
Its probably too crazy but you might get someones upload speed and size of video they are sending and make close to real progress bar. If testing upload speed in flash is possible it could work.